# Modifying ObservableCollection To Omit Repeated Child Values

Tags: c#, observablecollection

I have a custom class, let's call it MyObject, which represents something similar to a TreeView. My object has properties called `isSelected`, `title`, and `items`, `items` is a `List`, which can contain another `List` of items.

I created an ObservableCollection of MyObject, `ObservableCollection<MyObject> myCollection`.

myCollection returns data like this:

```
MyObject[index] -> isSelected, items[index], title -> items[index] -> isSelected, title
```

which looks like this when visualized:

```
RootTitle

    ChildItem Title

        ChildItem's ChildItem Title
    Repeated ChildItem
        ChildItem's ChildItem Title
```

My problem is, sometimes, my first ChildItem has a title that is repeated. When this happens, I want the data to look like this instead:

```
RootTitle

    ChildItem Title //only one, even if repeated title

        ChildItem's ChildItem Title // both childItem's ChildItem for the repeated title
        ChildItem's ChildItem Title
```

How can I modify my ObservableCollection to get this behavior?

This is the code I use to add items to the object, if it helps:

```
root = new MyObject() { Title = some.data.property.ToString() };
childItem = new MyObject() { Title = some.data.secondProperty.ToString() };
childItem.Items.Add(new MyObject() { Title = some.data.thirdProperty.ToString()() });
root.Items.Add(childItem);
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you could do something like this..

```
    root = new MyObject() { Title = some.data.property.ToString() };
.
.
.
    var repeated = root.Items.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.Title == some.data.secondProperty.ToString());
    if(repeated != null){
        repeated.Items.Add(new MyObject() { Title = some.data.thirdProperty.ToString()() });
    } else {
        childItem = new MyObject() { Title = some.data.secondProperty.ToString() };
        childItem.Items.Add(new MyObject() { Title = some.data.thirdProperty.ToString()();     
        root.Items.Add(childItem);
    }
```

I'm not sure if it's relevant for the "grandchildren" since you add them when you create the child, so it might be taken care of, but if you simplified the code for the question and it isn't you could do the same check in the else..